# Predicting probability of next event happening

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, markov-process, hidden-markov-model

My Data is:

- TimeStamp <- time stamp of the event occurring
- Length <- length is the duration of the event
- ID <- identifier where the event is occurring ( 25 IDs)

TimeStamp | Length | ID

The state of the machine between the events is 'upstate' and during the event is 'downstate'.

**Q 1) I want to predict the probability of next event happening and the approximate length for it.**

**Q 2) At a given time 't' in the future, I want to predict the if the state of the machine is 'upstate' or 'downstate'**

Of what I read, Hidden Markov models would be a good approach to use on this dataset. Are there any other suggestions that would be help me?

I am new to this type of datasets.

Comment: Great question. I edited your title to make the title more specific. Please check whether you are content with the new title.

Comment: @Ferdi: great no worries! I just hope to get an answer for this though.